# Cannot Access ABS-control-unit with ODB2-adapter

Tags: vw, obd-ii, electronic-control-module, abs

I have an ODB2-Bluetooth-Adapter([link](https://www.amazon.de/Bluetooth-Interface-Diagnose-Version-Testger%C3%A4t/dp/B004YG7J2I)) to access the ODB-Protocol with my android-smartphone.

It is basically working. The app that I use (["Torque"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.prowl.torquefree&hl=de)) can connect to the ECU, shows me different values like temperature, speed, pressure, load, and so on. I can also access the engine-control-unit of my car (2009 VW Polo 6r 1,4) and access it's fault codes.

However I have a problem with the ABS-control-unit. I got several warning lights in the dashboard, which are all related to the ABS (ESP, Tire-Pressure, and ABS). Now I wanted to use the app to show me what exactly is wrong (probably just a faulty sensor), but the app cannot access this ABS-control-unit. It can only find the engine-control-unit.
I also tried a different app (["Scan Master Light"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.wgsoft.scanmaster&hl=de)). This app lists all the available control-units of the car, but it only lists the one of the engine.

Where is the problem here? Is the adapter that I use not capabable of accessing other control-units than the engine? Or is it the application on the android? If so, do you know another application where I can actually read the fault-codes of the ABS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To my knowledge, access to the ABS module will not be possible through a generic OBDII adapter.

The most commonly available option for VW's of this era is a VAG-COM cable with [RossTech software](http://www.ross-tech.com) on a laptop.

Comment: Yes this is the correct awnser

Answer (score 3):

That particular sensor doesn't check ABS codes.  ABS errors are frequently on a different circuit entirely than check engine codes, and that particular device is only checking engine codes.

If you want a complete description of what your tester covers, try [this manual](https://www.elmelectronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/ELM327DS.pdf).